# Snap to month in highchart stock navigator

Tags: highcharts

I've got a chart that where allow the user to view the data grouped by day, week, or month. The problem is that if you use the navigator the month columns grow and shrink as the navigator moves or is resized. If the user moves the navigator to the middle of a month, the column graph above shows that that month is off by half. Is there a way to make the navigator be limited by monthly increments?

Answer (score 1):

Only solution is to use [afterSetExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) or [setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes) and there update extremes to required ones.

Comment: Hi can I ask how to do this without triggering an infinite loop? If I try to setExtremes in the afterSetExtremes function it will loop forever? I tried using chart.update but that isn't working...

Comment: Check `event.trigger` to prevent infinite loops. There's [`xAxis.setExtremes(min, max, redraw, animation, eventArgs)`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes) last argument `eventArgs` which can be later used in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, edited to UTC date

I also wrote in a 1 second delay to avoid it triggering too much

```
            events: {
                    afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
                        minFirstDay = new Date(e.min);
                        minFirstDay = Date.UTC(minFirstDay.getFullYear(), minFirstDay.getMonth(), 1);
                        maxFirstDay = new Date(e.max);
                        maxFirstDay = Date.UTC(maxFirstDay.getFullYear(), maxFirstDay.getMonth(), 1);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            if (e.min != minFirstDay || e.max != maxFirstDay) {
                                navChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(minFirstDay, maxFirstDay);
                                console.log('date range updated');
                            };
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
```